# Is it required to check the runtime permission WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE when downloading a file with the DownloadManager?

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-download-manager

In my app I'm not checking the permission at runtime. My app targets the SDK 25 and I've added

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

in the manifest.

From my tests, the app doesn't crash, probably because DownloadManager is a system service and it's not my app directly to download the file.

Is my reasoning correct or should I add the runtime check to request the permission to the user? I wouldn't want the app to crash when deployed on some devices.

Thanks!

Comment: On Android P, it appears that you need the permission: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/75161040

Comment: I create the app which needs runtime permission to cache pictures but it doesn't crash if it doesn't even ask a user for a permission. You can clearly see it in the log when you launch the app. You should get (Permission denied). If I were you, I would check the log but I'm sure it will show "Permission denied" and skip the process. Add runtime permission to your code.